# Something is wrong with if statement's logic

Tags: ruby

I have a method that checks if the user completed his profile information:

```
def checkUser
  if (current_user.fullname.nil? && current_user.availability.nil? && current_user.rate.nil? && current_user.terms.nil? && current_user.location_city.nil? && current_user.location_state.nil? && current_user.location_country.nil? && current_user.biography.nil?)
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

When I tried it seemed that something was wrong. The rate attributed was empty (nil) and the fullname attribute was not empty.

I was debugging and figured out that `current_user.rate.nil?` was returning as `true` and `current_user.rate.nil?` was returning `false` which is normal. However, by using Rails.logger.info I figured out that the checkUser method was returning `true` rather than `false`.

I am not sure if the way I used for returning true or false is appropriate. Does the return true or false in the if condition represent the return value of the checkUser method?

Comment: Consider reading about how condition branches work.

Comment: It is not normal for `current_user.rate.nil?` to return `true` if it returns `false`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meditate on this:

```
def checkUser
  if (current_user.fullname.nil? && current_user.availability.nil? && current_user.rate.nil? && current_user.terms.nil? && current_user.location_city.nil? && current_user.location_state.nil? && current_user.location_country.nil? && current_user.biography.nil?)
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

Could be written like:

```
def valid?
  current_user.fullname.nil? && 
  current_user.availability.nil? && 
  current_user.rate.nil? && 
  current_user.terms.nil? && 
  current_user.location_city.nil? && 
  current_user.location_state.nil? && 
  current_user.location_country.nil? && 
  current_user.biography.nil?
end
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
def valid?
  [
    current_user.fullname, 
    current_user.availability, 
    current_user.rate, 
    current_user.terms, 
    current_user.location_city, 
    current_user.location_state, 
    current_user.location_country, 
    current_user.biography
  ].all?{ |v| v.nil? }
end
```

But that can even be reduced to:

```
def valid?
  [
    :fullname, 
    :availability, 
    :rate, 
    :terms, 
    :location_city, 
    :location_state, 
    :location_country, 
    :biography
  ].all?{ |m| current_user.send(m).nil? }
end
```

Things to consider:

- The last value seen in a method will be automatically returned by Ruby. That means you don't have to say `return true` or `return false` if the comparison already returns a true or false value. In fact, it's considered bad Ruby style to use an explicit `return some_value` if it's not needed because it wastes typing, space, and essential brain energy to read.
- Method names in Ruby are written in snake_case, not camelCase. It seems_like_a_small_thing untilYouTryToReadSomeAwfulLongNameAndYourBrainRebels.
- Method names read better when they're a verb or ask a question. "check_user" is OK, but it's more idiomatic to call such a method "valid?" or "is_ok?" since you want a boolean true/false response.

Comment: on the last example, what if I use || rather than &&?

Comment: Try it and see. `||` is not the same as `&&`, and won't act like a replacement unless you do some mind-bending "not" alterations to it, which will make the logic a lot harder to understand.

Comment: i see. what I am saying is on the last example you used ".all?" which I assume is used in replacing all the && I used. What if I use || instead of the &&? is there something to use for this case instead of .all?

Comment: Use `any?{ |m| current_user.send(m) }`. Read the [Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html) documentation. It's chock-full of useful things like that.

Comment: excellent! i know its bad to say thank you in comments here in SO but what you posted here is a gem and really helpful. Thanks a million. I wish I could buy you a drink for all that! You are awesome!

Comment: You're welcome; That's what we do here. This is all about learning to recognize patterns in code, and knowing how to reduce things down. I've spent a lot of time making the mistakes, learning how to improve my code, and trying to reduce it down to something succinct and readable.

Answer (score 2):

An empty string is not the same as `nil`. If a user doesn't enter anything, it may simply be the empty string, which is not nil.

```
"".nil?
"".empty?
```

In addition, your method only returns true if everything is `nil`. This doesn't seem like the right logic. I'm assuming you want it to return true if any of the fields have not been filled in?

Answer (score 1):

There is lots of room for improvement here.

First, ditch the return keyword as it's only neccessary for shortcircuiting methods. E.g.

```
def age_category
  return "unknown" if age.nil?

  if age < 0
    "unborn"
  elsif age < 18
    "child"
  elsif age < 65
    "adult"
  elsif age < 120
    "senior"
  else
    "ancient"
  end  
end
```

Since the if/else condition is the last part of the method, the output of the condition will be the return value of the method.

With that in mind, we can rewrite:

```
def checkUser
  if (current_user.fullname.nil? && current_user.availability.nil? && current_user.rate.nil? && current_user.terms.nil? && current_user.location_city.nil? && current_user.location_state.nil? && current_user.location_country.nil? && current_user.biography.nil?)
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

However, the condition checked returns a boolean itself, so there is no need for the if/else. Just evaluate the parenthesis.

```
def checkUser
  (current_user.fullname.nil? && current_user.availability.nil? && current_user.rate.nil? && current_user.terms.nil? && current_user.location_city.nil? && current_user.location_state.nil? && current_user.location_country.nil? && current_user.biography.nil?)
end
```

However, all of this code is not object-oriented at all. Why do you have a method somewhere that does intense examination of a user object to determine if it is complete? A user object should be able to tell you this, so you can write:

```
def check_user
  current_user.complete?
end
```

On the user class, you can then implement the following method

```
def complete?
  [fullname, availability, rate, terms, location_city, location_state, location_country, biography].none? {|attribute| attribute.to_s.empty?}
end
```

This method creates an array with all your attributes. It then turns each of them into a string to check if they are empty. If none of your attributes are empty, the method returns true.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` keyword will immediately stop execution of the method and return whatever value is passed to it. In this case, true or false.